# parsing XML to CSV in node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, csv

I am trying to convert an xml file to csv file using node.js diretly.

My xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597138973</responseData>
</httpSample>
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597139525</responseData>
</httpSample>
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597139716</responseData>
</httpSample>
</testResults>
```

I am able to get the value of `<responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597138973</responseData>`.
But I also want to parse the value of `ts="1501597136964"` and `lb="req_10"` from `<httpSample>` tag

I am using `xml2rec` package

```
var xml2rec=require('xml2rec');
xml2rec('xmlFile.xml', 'httpSample', 'csvFile.csv');
```

Should I be checking any other packages that can help me do this or I have to go the long way to convert from **xml to json** first and then **json to csv**??
Also, in doing so, will I be able to get the value of `ts` and `lb` attributes of `httpSample` tag??

*P.S. The output xml file is JMeter response file*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's the best way to do this but since xml structure is not flat anyway, you will have to flatten it before converting to csv.

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse

const xml = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597138973</responseData>
</httpSample>
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597139525</responseData>
</httpSample>
<httpSample ts="1501597136964" lb="req_10">
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">1501597139716</responseData>
</httpSample>
</testResults>
`
const template = {
    data: ['//httpSample', {
        ts: '@ts',
        lb: '@lb',
        resp: 'responseData'
    }]
}

const result = transform(xml, template)
const csv = json2csv(result.data)
console.log(csv)
```

Output:

```
"lb","resp","ts"
"req_10","1501597138973","1501597136964"
"req_10","1501597139525","1501597136964"
"req_10","1501597139716","1501597136964"
```

Comment: So we do usually go from **xml to json** and then **json to csv**... Let me try if this is helpful in my case.